# Grant/Permit all MySQL User Defined Functions under a database to a user

Tags: mysql, permissions, stored-functions

How can I grant execute permission for all of the user defined functions under a database to a particular user? A new user may execute/run all functions defined by some other users.

```
1. GRANT ALL ON DATABASE.* TO 'USERNAME'@'HOSTNAME';
2. GRANT EXECUTE ON DATABASE.* TO 'USERNAME'@'HOSTNAME';
```

Both of these attempts failed to permit a new user. And the following call ends with an error.

```
SELECT f_custom_function();
```

Corresponding Error Message:

```
Query : ____
Error Code : 1370
execute command denied to user 'USERNAME'@'HOSTNAME' for routine 'DATABASE.f_custom_function'
```

Comment: GRANT ALL ON DATABASE.* TO 'USERNAME'@'HOSTNAME';
DATABASE should be changed to some other name

Comment: These CAPs are for hints only.

Answer (score 2):

The following will give execute privilege to one user for **all objects** within one database:

```
GRANT EXECUTE
  ON *.*
  TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
```

---

This alternative allows access to a single [MySQL user defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618804/mysql-user-defined-functions) for a single user:

```
GRANT EXECUTE
  ON FUNCTION `mydatabase`.`myuserdefunc`
  TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
```

---

*Note: the `mydatabase`, `myuser`, and `myuserdefunc`; are for example only and are to be replaced with the values appropriate to your project.*

Comment: granting execute on all objects may not desirable from a security perspective. can someone comment on any security issues from granting execute on all objects, please?